# Как добавить несколько пользовательских реакций на один пост через telegram api

Tags: api, telegram

С помощью  telegram api и messages.sendReaction отправляю пользовательскую реакцию на пост и все работает.Но я хочу оправить несколько реакций на один пост, причем от премиум пользователя. Такая возможность есть если устанавливать их вручную. Но можно как-то через api? Если оправляю последовательно, то они просто замещаются.